# load image with css class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have class which create a button type background. How to load a icon image before text like this?

[image]

### html

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; position: absolute; height: 3em;width: 100%;">               
    <div id="Body_inputUpload" class="uploadify"><object id="SWFUpload_0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Images/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1396906987080" width="120" height="30" class="swfupload" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></object>
  <div id="Body_inputUpload-button" class="uploadify-button fileUploaderBtn">
         <span class="uploadify-button-text">Upload</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Body_inputUpload-queue" class="uploadify-queue"></div>
```

### css

```
.uploadify {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.fileUploaderBtn {
border: .1em #868686 solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: Segoe UI;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
text-align: left;
color: #000000;
background-color: #f4f5f5;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f5f5, #dfdddd);
    height: 25px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 81px;
}
```

want to load this image
[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLeJs/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add that image in :before

add this css:

```
.fileUploaderBtn:before {
    content: "";
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMV1.png") center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

and change width: 81px; to min-width: 81px; in .fileUploadBtn class.

here's example in JSFillde: http://jsfiddle.net/cLeJs/4/

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the DOM, you can just insert the image via an `img` tag placed right before the `span` containing the text "upload". Here is a fiddle showing that option: http://jsfiddle.net/72M8h/

Answer (score 0):

You only have to place the img tag before the text span:

`<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMV1.png" />`
`<span class="uploadify-button-text">Upload</span>`

Here is the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLeJs/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles to the following classes:

```
.uploadify-button-text{
padding-left: 30px;
background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMV1.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

I personally think its better to use background images so that you can add hover states if you like, and remove width off .fileUploaderBtn  There is no need to give the button a specific width in this case. If you want the button to have a specific width, alter the padding.

Answer (score 0):

just add your image with `:before` , in front of text 'Upload' **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cLeJs/5/)**
Your HTML

```
<span class="uploadify-button-text">Upload</span>
```

CSS that you can use to 'load' image within.

```
.uploadify-button-text:before {
    content:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMV1.png)' ';/* image + 1 white-space */
    vertical-align:-0.2em;/* tune this if needed */
}
```